# Get the text of a combo box Win32 API C++ (NO MFC)

Tags: c++, winapi, api, text, combobox

I am trying to setup a combo box so a user can select an option from the dropdown menu and then retrieve what the user selected using Win32 API C++ programming, not MFC. I read John's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117619/get-set-combo-box-text-in-win32-not-mfc) and I could not get anything to work. I can set the text for the combo box, but I cannot retrieve what the user selected. Here are a few methods I have tried:

```
                LPTSTR buf;
                ComboBox_GetText(hwnd, buf, 9);
                MessageBox(NULL, buf, NULL, MB_OK);
```

And

```
                char* buf;
                GetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_COMBO1, buf, 9);
                MessageBox(NULL, buf, NULL, MB_OK);
```

`IDC_COMBO1` is the ID of the combo box and `hwnd` is the HWND of the current dialog box.
The code for my dialog box with the combo box is:

`LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
IDD_DIALOG4 DIALOG 0, 0, 424, 181
STYLE DS_3DLOOK | DS_CENTER | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_SHELLFONT | WS_CAPTION | WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "Ms Shell Dlg"
{
    COMBOBOX        IDC_COMBO1, 113, 31, 119, 19, CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_HASSTRINGS
    PUSHBUTTON      "Button1", IDC_BUTTON1, 188, 112, 50, 14
}`

I am using a resource file to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? How does it fail? What is the error code?

Comment: It does not give me any data. I am not getting any error codes, it compiles correctly it just does not return the data in the text box when I call the message box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the call to ComboBox_GetText the hwnd parameter must be the handle to the combo box itself, not the dialog. You can get that HWND with `GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_COMBO1);`

Also, you can't pass an uninitialized pointer to either function; you must pass a pointer to a buffer which you have created.

```
            char buf[10];
            GetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_COMBO1, buf, 9);
            MessageBox(NULL, buf, NULL, MB_OK);
```

Comment: I tried doing `char* buf;
                    HWND Cbobox;
                    Cbobox = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_COMBO1);
                    ComboBox_GetText(Cbobox, buf, 9);
                    MessageBox(NULL, buf, NULL, MB_OK);` but that did not get me anywhere, it still gave be a blank return string. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @Shadowalker, I realized the problem just a few moments before you commented, see my update.

Comment: @David Heffernan since ComboBox_GetText is a macro that expands to GetWindowText I suspect you're 100% correct. That led me to reexamine my answer and hopefully I've found the root cause this time.

Comment: I was afraid it was something simple as that. Thanks, that worked.

Comment: @Mark Gahh I should have seen that!!

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, you need to use [ComboBox_GetCurSel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb856471%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to determine which item is selected and then you can use [ComboBox_GetLBText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb856477%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get the actual text.