# Win32 C++ getting text from elements

Tags: c++, winapi, selectlist

While this question has probably been asked a thousand times before (pretty sure of it I have read a thousand answers). I still don't get it.

Lets say I have a function that creates a ComboBox like this:

```
  scopeComboSelector=CreateCombobox(hwnd,
                                    GetModuleHandle(0),
                                    CBS_DROPDOWNLIST,
                                    re,
                                    IDCC_DROPDOWNLIST_SCOPE_SELECTOR,
                                    _T("Scopes"));
```

Where "re" is a positioning rectangle. And IDCC_DROPDOWNLIST_SCOPE_SELECTOR (pretty long name) is the id of the combobox. Now the point is, I can actually fill this "drop down select list" but I have no clue as how I can simply get the currently selected value as a string.

I have seen about 10 ways to do it, which all give errors straight away (need to Convert to LPWSTR -> fixing results in more terror).

Maybe I'm just to used to Java where one can simply say:

```
 textfield.getText();
```

How would one achieve this in Win32 C++ (microsoft visual studio)?

**Edit**

Code I've used:

```
  char userName[_MAX_PATH+1];
  GetDlgItemTextW(scopeComboSelector,
                  IDCC_DROPDOWNLIST_SCOPE_SELECTOR,
                 (LPWSTR)userName,
                  200);
```

Returns: userName == empty

**Update**

Now using: GetDlgItemText(). Debugger tells me the value of userName = ""

Comment: Please post the code for the way you have tried, and the exact error you got. It sounds like you probably had the right answer at some point, but just weren't handling the strings properly. If you post that info, someone can probably show you where you went wrong.

Comment: Looks like you're using a `char` array in a function which is expecting unicode. Try `GetDlgItemText` instead of `GetDlgItemTextW`, or use a wide char instead of char. Also, please post the compiler error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262644/get-the-text-of-a-combo-box-win32-api-c-no-mfc

Comment: First of all you need to understand casting. You appear to believe that the solution to type mismatch is to cast the error away. That is not the solution. Don't do that! Fix the root problem and pass data of the correct type. Since you are using the Unicode API, use `wchar_t` rather than `char`.

Comment: Now, what is `purposeComboSelector`? Your combo is `scopeComboSelector`. You are also failing to check return values and error codes. You need to do that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I take it you are referring to (LPWSTR) ? But removing that makes the compiler tell me he needs LPWSTR and not char*

Comment: Sorry I have 2 of those boxes and mixed the code I will update it straight away

Comment: So give it `LPWSTR` like the compiler says. Pretending that you are giving it `LPWSTR` does not make it so. You need `wchar_t userName[_MAX_PATH+1];` And then you need to start checking return values.

Comment: I made it a wchar_t like you suggested and it turns out the compiler does not mind this for the function input. But the wchar_t (uncasted now) is still ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has a C style Windows 9x code example.

You need simply to replace C with C++ and Windows 9x silly T macros with `wchar_t` and friends.

It's always a good idea to read the documentation.